# "Please explain" or "explain please"

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, adverbs, word-order

Which one is correct in this context?

> Person A:  I think Apple will displace Google.
>   Person B:  Please explain.

Should he say/write "Explain please"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both

> Please explain

and

> Explain, please

are grammatically correct. However, the former is vastly more common, and more to the point, it is also quite a bit more **polite**. Putting the *please* at the end makes it obvious that this is a command; putting the *please* first makes it more of a request.

Answer (score 3):

You can write "please explain," or "explain, please."

I prefer "please explain," but that is just a matter of style; both the phrases are perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3):

An adverb (*please*) may precede or follow the verb it modifies, so either would be correct, though you would probably want a comma for the latter:

> Explain, please.

However, as you can see from [this nGram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=please+explain%2C+explain+please&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), *please explain* is far more commonly used.

Comment: (+1) Without the comma, "explain _please_" seems more like a request to explain the meaning or purpose of a polite word.  Similarly, a demand to "explain _now_" (without the comma) is very different from a demand to "explain, _now_" (with the comma).

Answer (score 2):

I would say `Please explain` is more suitable here. Not that I know so much about it but that sounds more appropriate for me to use please at the end of the sentence when I am using it with a noun;

> Licence, please.

Answer (score 0):

Order:  Expain please
Request: Please explain

Both look correct but the Please explain is much more common while the other might be common in the Army.

Comment: Why would "explain please" be more common in the Army?

Comment: Since its formal and please expain would sound casual in the Army.